# Music track class

Tags: python

This is my first time working with classes and it's still unclear to me. I was wondering if someone can tell me if I did this right.

> Define a new class, Track, that has an artist (a string), a title
>   (also a string), and an album (see below).
>
> 1. Has a method `__init__`(self, artist, title, album=None). The arguments artist and and title are strings and album is an Album
>      object (see below)
> 2. Has a method `__str__`(self) that returns a reasonable string representation of this track
> 3. Has a method set_album(self, album) that sets this track's album to album

```
class Track:
    def __init__(self, artist, title, album=None):
        self.artist = str(artist)
        self.title = str(title)
        self.album = album

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist + " " + self.title + " " + self.album

    def set_album(self, album):
        self.album = album

Track = Track("Andy", "Me", "Self named")
```

Comment: The `set_album` method is redundant and _unpythonic_: simply assign to the attribute directly in your code. If at any point in the future you need some more complicated behaviour when setting the attribute, look into using a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) then.

Comment: @PedroRomano - agreed, but it seems as though the homework question (I assume it's homework?) is explicitly asking for the method `set_album`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, looks great! A few things:

1. This relates to 'new-style' classes in Python - make sure that they inherit from `object`. It sounds like you are learning about classes now, so I will spare an explanation of what inheritance is since you'll eventually get to it.
2. I could be misguided in saying this, but generally I've seen/done type conversion (where you call `str()`) outside of the constructor (i.e. the `__init__()` function). The instructions says it expects a string, and you are already passing a string in the `Track =` line, so removing the `str()` parts will still result in the correct answer.
3. The instructions say that `album` is an "Album object", which means that `Album` will be a class as well. I'm assuming you're just getting this started so it hasn't been created yet, but when you do, you can just pass the `Album` object into your `Track` constructor.
4. Naming - in general, avoid naming your instances the same thing as the class (in your case, `Track` is the class). This leads to confusion, especially when you need to create a second instance (because `Track` will then an instance of Track, instead of the `Track` class.

Here is your same code with a few of those adjustments. In general though, looking good!

```
class Track(object):
    def __init__(self, artist, title, album=None):
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.album = album

    def __str__(self):
        # This is called 'string formatting' and lets you create a template string
        # and then plug in variables, like so
        return "%s - %s (%s)" % (self.artist, self.title, self.album)

    def set_album(self, album):
        self.album = album

my_track = Track("Andy", "Me", "Self named")

# This will show you what __str__ does
print my_track
```

Comment: Regarding point 1: you don't need to inherit from `object` in Python 3.x. I can't tell what version he's using. Also, the `%` formatting operator [has been superseded by `string.format()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) (though of course the old style is still hugely common).

Comment: @poorsod Agreed - I actually don't ever use the % operator :) Figured it would be the easier one to explain, but am looking forward to a `.format()`-only future! As to inheriting from `object`, I blindly assumed that he was using 2.x - I need to get with the future I guess :)